# Question based on $n$ sided regular polygon.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $n$ sided regular polygon
>
> $(a)$ Total number of $\triangle$ formed in which none of the sides are the sides of that polygon
>
> $(b)\; $Total number of  equilateral $\triangle$ formed in by joining the vertices of that polygon
>
> $(c)\; $Total number of  right angle $\triangle$ formed in by joining the vertices of that polygon

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ For $(a)$ one,

$\triangle$ with no side common $=$Total  $\triangle-\triangle$ with one side common$-\triangle$ with $2$ side common

So we get $$\displaystyle = \binom{n}{3}-(n)\cdot (n-4)-n$$

Now, how can I solve other $2$ parts? Help required. Thanks.

Comment: Are you constructing the chords of said polygon?

Comment: This may help: http://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/papers/stars/default.html

Comment: Yes  Justin Benfield.

Answer (score 1):

Hints for (b) and (c):

The given conditions enforce conditions on $n$. Think of peripheral and central angles. In particular: If two diagonals meet at an angle of $60^\circ$ their other endpoints subtend an angle of  $120^\circ$ at the center. This is only possible if $n$ satisfies a certain condition.

Comment: Thanks Christian Blatter, Would you like to explain me in detail